# XSLT Transformation of XML File

Tags: xslt, serialization

I've written a simple XML Document that I am trying to transform with an XSLT file, but I get no results when I run the code.  Here is my XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Employee xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xmlns="XSLT_MVC.Controllers">
  <ID>42</ID>
  <Name>Russ</Name>
</Employee>
```

And here is the XSLT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
   xmlns:ex="XSLT_MVC.Controllers" >
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="ex:Employee/Name"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the code (from a C# console app) I am trying to run to perform the transform:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Xsl;
using System.Xml.XPath;

namespace XSLT
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Transform();
    }

    public static void Transform()
    {
        XPathDocument myXPathDoc = new XPathDocument(@"docs\sampledoc.xml");
        XslTransform myXslTrans = new XslTransform();
        myXslTrans.Load(@"docs\new.xslt");

        XmlTextWriter myWriter = new XmlTextWriter(
            "results.html", null);

        myXslTrans.Transform(myXPathDoc, null, myWriter);

        myWriter.Close();
    }
}
}
```

When I run the code I get a blank html file.  I think I may have problems with the namespaces, but am not sure.  Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Please, provide the source XML document on which the transformation is applied. Also needed is the desired output.

Comment: Dimitre, sorry, I guess I wasn't very clear on the source of the XML.  I don't have an actual XML document, but am using the DataContractSerializer to serialize my Employee Class to XML in the GetDoc() function of the Employee class.  The serialized XML returned from GetDoc() looks like this:
    <Employee>
      <ID>42</ID>
      <Name>Russ</Name>
    </Employee>
The html output I want to get back is simply the Employee ID, Name, the two radio buttons for Approve or Reject, and a submit button.

Comment: To All:  I edited my code above to remove the DataContractSerializer and just use an XML document instead.  I think this is much simpler than my original post was, and hopefully I haven't introduced confusion by changing this post so much.

Comment: Try adding namespace to both elems: select="ex:Employee/ex:Name"

Comment: Steven - Thanks for your help, adding the namespace to both elements works just fine.  If you will post this suggestion as an Answer, I'll mark it as the accepted answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem turned out to be adding namespace to both elems: select="ex:Employee/ex:Name", as Steven Majewski suggested in his comment above.  He hasn't posted this as an answer, so I am posting it.

Answer (score 0):

Would you just want to match on Employee?  And then select name from that?
Also, I've noticed your XSLT specifies an output of XML rather than HTML.

Comment: Chris, Thanks for the help.  I changed the XSLT to match on Employee, and changed it to out HTML, and it dumps both of the properties out to the HTML file like this: 42Russ.  If I try to do a select like this: <xsl:value-of select="Name"/> after the match="Employee", it doesn't seem to process that line.